# Return mongojs query result from function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I made the function below for getting usernames from ids. It is not working well.
I can write console.log(result.first_name); within the query function, and the usernames shows up in my terminal, but not the browser. I tried adding “return 'something';” at the end of the function, to see if that showed up in the browser – It did. How can I write the function so that the query result is returned?

function (global function in app.js)

```
function usernameFromId(id, callback){
    db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id.toString()) }, function(err, result) {
        var first_name = result.first_name;
        console.log(first_name); // names show up in the console…
        callback(first_name);
    });
};
```

page handler (in app.js)

```
app.get('/books', function(req, res){
    function timeSince(dato){
        moment.lang('nb');
        return moment(dato).fromNow();
    };
    db.books.find().sort({ added:-1 }, function(err, docs) {
        var books = docs;
        db.activity.find().limit(9).sort({ time:-1 }, function(err, docs) {
            var activity = docs;
            res.render('books', {
                books: books,
                activity: activity,
                timeSince: timeSince,
                usernameFromId: usernameFromId
            })
        });
    });
});
```

template (books.jade)

```
- each a in activity
    p=usernameFromId(a.user_id, function(name){return name;})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. Not sure whether it’s any good, but it works. No need for a function.

page handler (in app.js):

```
app.get('/books', function(req, res){
    db.activity.find().limit(9).sort({ time:-1 }, function(err, docs) {
        var activity = docs;
        db.users.find(function(err, docs) {
            var users = docs;
            res.render('books', {
                page_title:'books',
                activity: activity,
                users: users
            })
        });
    });
});
```

template (books.jade):

```
- each a in activity
    - for u in users
        - if (a.user_id == u._id.toString())
            | #{u.first_name}
```

Comment: You can wrap your response in a closure to make it more testable.  And then pass the closure as the callback to the query -- so you can substitute it out with a mock or something that doesn't require HTTP.  See my response to my own similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972763/how-to-use-events-keep-mongodb-logic-out-of-node-js-request-handlers

Comment: This seems like a really hacky solution. I would think there would be a more intuitive way than repeated nested mongojs queries.

Answer (score 2):

No because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.  I have added some comments to your code to indicate the actual order of execution.  This is why you are getting the error.

```
function usernameFromId(id){
    var id = id.toString(); // 1
    db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, function(err, result) {
        var first_name = result.first_name; // 3
    });
    return first_name; // 2
};
```

Edit: you probably want something like the following

```
function usernameFromId(id, callback){
    var id = id.toString();
    db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, function(err, result) {
        var first_name = result.first_name; 
        callback(first_name);
    });
};
```

Comment: I’m getting this: “Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function”

Comment: Are you feeding in a callback function after id? e.g. usernameFromId(4, function(name) {console.log(name);});

Comment: Thanks, the names shows up in the terminal, but how do I return strings from a callback function?

Comment: I tried that, it gives no error as i can see, but the names are not showing up.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling usernameFromId from within Jade.  Call it from within app.js and capture the output and feed through to your Jade template

Comment: Should I do that with timeSince too, why?

Comment: Without being disrespectful I think you should brush up on some JavaScript basics.  I feel like I'm writing a tutorial in the comments section.

Comment: One minor point about execution order -- it calls db.users.findOne() before return, but it returns before findOne() completes